# XTK change the height and width of a canvas

Tags: xtk

I would know if it possible to change the height and the width of a canvas genarated after the init of a X.render2D of a volume object(.nii.gz)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the height and width of the container div and then fire a window resize event. XTK catches the event and adjusts the canvas according to the container height and width after that.